# Javascript: Automation of button click

Tags: javascript, automation, ui-automation

I'm generation a html button:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="imageWin(12344,'yyyy','120','someId');" class="Button">Click</a>
```

But I'm trying to automate clicking on the button using javascript.

Any of you knows how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it :

```
var btn = document.getElementByClassName("Button");
btn.click();
```

or `imageWin(12344,'yyyy','120','someId')`